# why do wrapper classes NOT inherit basic datatypes?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I was looking at the `UserDict` class source and I am kind of perturbed to see:

```
class UserDict:
  def __init__(self, dict=None, **kwargs):
    self.data = {}
    if dict is not None:
      self.update(dict)
    ...
```

and then methods like:

```
def keys(self): return self.data.keys()
def items(self): return self.data.items()
def iteritems(self): return self.data.iteritems()
def iterkeys(self): return self.data.iterkeys()
def itervalues(self): return self.data.itervalues()
def values(self): return self.data.values()
```

Wouldn't it have been better to do:

```
class UserDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, dict=None, **kwargs):
    #self.data = {}                            # now self itself is {}
    if dict is not None:
      self.update(dict)
    ...
```

**and then the need for aforementioned methods would simply go away.**

Moreover it also helps a programmer learn on the very outset that `UserDict` extends the functionality of dict by looking the class definition itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they're older than the ability to inherit from the basic datatypes. Modifying them to do so could have broken existing programs in various ways.

Answer (score 4):

Before Python 2.2 you couldn't subclass `dict`.  `UserDict` only exists for backwards compatibility.

See http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html

Comment: +1 for docs. @Vaibhav Bajpai, a general principle that I try to follow is, before getting irritated about something, read the documentation.